# How can I make sure to always connect to the same docker container?

Tags: docker, ip, containers

I have a little problem with really understanding this.
When I start 3 containers in Docker they get 3 different IP-Addresses, that are assigned sequentially, I can address them from other containers and everything works fine.
But when I start a different container before those 3, the 3 get different IP-Addresses and the entire setup goes to hell.

I have been pestering Google for quite a while now, but I don't seem to find a proper (and not too complicated) solution to have one steady way to connect to a certain container. It's not that I want to assign the IP myself, just to tell the docker host something like "every time container X starts, assign the IP 172.17.0.X to it"
There must be some way in which the order in which I start up the containers doesnt matter, it can't be that I have to change my settings every other time I restart containers.

So some help here would be nice?
Some way in which I can assign IPs to a container or give it some sort of alias that I can address from another container.

Comment: "It's not that I want to assign the IP myself, just to tell the docker host something like "every time container X starts, assign the IP 172.17.0.X to it"" That sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect from container to another container through ip it is not the "docker-way", so the really proper way is using of `--link`as posted [Nguyen Sy Thanh Son](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287386/nguyen-sy-thanh-son).
As example:

`docker run --name=db image1
docker run --name=app --link outernamedb:internalname image2`

and then inside of `app` container use `internalname:3306`

But it will not work if you try to start `app` **before** `db`, for that case there is kind a legal hack for docker higher than 1.11.
From [docker official docks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/run) you can use `--ip` flag to set exact ip for container

`docker run --name=db --ip 172.17.0.90 image1
docker run --name=app --ip 172.17.0.91 image2`

and then inside of `app` container use `172.17.0.90:3306`

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use `hostname` instead of IP Address in your Docker containers. And when you run Docker containers, you are able to use `--link` between the container. See https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links

In the new version, It is easy to connect the containers together in same network. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Docker Networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/). Links are being deprecated and the IP address stuff is a craziness :)

```
$ docker network create my-net
$ docker run -d --net my-net --name container1 image1
$ docker run -d --net my-net --name container2 image2
$ docker exec -it container1 sh
# ping container2
PING container2 (172.21.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find some information on this post

[How do I set up a DNS container inside docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846611/how-do-i-set-up-a-dns-container-inside-docker-compose/37861290#37861290)

i hope this helped ;)